# Do accompanying tools/scripts also need to be licensed to put my bash script under GPLv3?

Tags: gpl, bash

This is some sort of follow up to an older [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/158919/1320) of me.

So I put the GPLv3 license into the project which contains my script and also added the copyright notice and copying permission statement to the top of my script.

Now, apart from the script, the package also contains files which are helpful for using the script (e.g. a bash completion file and unit tests) but which are not relevant for the script to actually work. Do I also need to put copyright notice/permission in there?

I've looked into some projects on github, and most don't seem to add these information to accompanying things.

Still, I'm unsure what's the best approach.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the GPL licenses for exactly this reason.  Do you absolutely have to go with GPL, or can you consider some other license such as Apache, MIT or BSD?

Comment: @GordonM The GPL was the first thing that came to my mind but going with another license would also be okay for me. Maybe I need more information on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put a copyright and license header into each file, even if you publish them under a different license. This way, you avoid that your users experience the same confusion that made you ask your question.